# Deploy angular8 production build in .netcore 3.0

Tags: .net-core, angular8

I am developing an angular 8 project. How can I deploy the angular production build in web root folder(wwwroot) of a .netcore3.0 web api project. I have added 'app.UseDefaultFiles()' and 'app.UseStaticFiles()' commands in the middleware but it seems to be not working.

Comment: What is the response when you request: `/`?

Comment: This localhost page can’t be found. HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: Can you show us what's under your `wwwroot` folder?

Comment: wwwroot has only  'dist' folder, which is the angular build.

Comment: No. Please put the content in the dist folder under `wwwroot`. Not the folder under `wwwroot`

Comment: 'dist' has 'ProjectName' folder, 'assets' folder, index.html, and some js files(polyfills, main, runtime, etc.)

Comment: Yeah. Once there is the `index.html` file under your `wwwroot` folder, your app is likely to be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Please refer to [Kestrel as a Static Server for Angular](https://tattoocoder.com/kestrel-as-a-static-server-for-angular/). Then in Program.cs add the following:

```cs
static string webRoot = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "wwwroot");
```

and then add `UseWebRoot(webRoot)` in `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`.

Comment: This also worked for a bare-bone IdentityServer4 deployment. Thanks for sharing